# Cannot call temporary layer while polygonizing a raster on PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, polygonize, template

I been trying to call the resulting vector from the Raster Poligonization but it ends up telling me:

> Unable to execute algorithm. Could not load source layer for INPUT:
> */OUTPUT.tif not found Execution failed after 0.32 seconds

Here is the code:

```
waterbodies = 'waterbodies'
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
        self.waterbodies,
        self.tr("Input waterbodies"),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeRaster]))
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

    processing.run("gdal:polygonize", 
    {'INPUT': waterbodies_r, 'BAND': 1, 'FIELD': 'DN','EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS': False, 'EXTRA': '', 'OUTPUT': output_path_vector})
```

It probably has to do with it not recognizing the output as Vector but I am not sure on how to solve this issue...

Comment: Does anybody has an idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Where do you create the `waterbodies_r` variable? It would be easier to figure out the issue with a more complete code...